# ClientSide JavaScript communicating with C# Server

Tags: javascript, c#, server

I have a C# Server that has information on it and my goal is to be able to run a piece of JavaScript Code that grabs this information from the C# Server without any PHP. How would I go about doing this?

Thought I would add that I am not looking someone to hold my hand I just need a nudge in the right direction

Comment: How your c# server works? If using TPC/IP and HTTP, you can use standart AJAX.

Comment: Thank you that was literally the answer I was needing I was having a dumb moment and couldn't figure out how to go about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take some time to read through [Dave Ward's excellent documentation on Encosia.com regarding using ASP.NET, JQuery & AJAX](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/?ref=sidebar_most_popular).  That's where I learned how to move data back and forth using JS & AJAX.  Well worth the time and the read.